# GCC on windows compiling to a library?

Tags: windows, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I have a make file that I use in an Eclipse CDT project

```
OBJECTS=     APREP.o CANADD.o CANALB.o CANVAP.o  \
        CGROW.o CHKWAT.o CLASSA.o  CLASSB.o CLASSBD.o \
        CLASSD.o CLASSG.o CLASSI.o CLASSS.o CLASST.o CLASSW.o \
        CLASSZ.o CWCALC.o DIASURFZ.o DRCOEF.o FLXSURFZ.o \
        GATPREP.o GRALB.o GRDRAN.o GRINFL.o ICEBAL.o  \
        SCREENRH.o SLDIAG.o SNINFL.o SNOADD.o SNOALBA.o SNOALBW.o \
        SNOVAP.o SUBCAN.o TFREEZ.o TMCALC.o TMELT.o TNPOST.o TNPREP.o \
        TPREP.o TSOLVC.o TSOLVE.o TSPOST.o TSPREP.o TWCALC.o WEND.o \
        WFILL.o WFLOW.o WPREP.o XIT.o RUNCLASS.o

# ======================================================================
# Declaring variables
# ======================================================================

# The Compiler
FC=gfortran

# Flag for compiling and debugging - comment as necessary
LFLAG=-c 

# Flag for debugging
#LFLAG=-c -g

# ======================================================================
# Build CLASS executable and print message
# ======================================================================
CLASS: ${OBJECTS}
    $(FC) -o CLASS  $(OBJECTS)
    @echo ---*---
    @echo ---*---
    @echo CLASS is now up to date...
    @echo ---*---
    @echo ---*---
```

This creates an exe CLASS.exe. How do I change that to be a includable library? - an .so or .a file in windows.